# Where is the error in my code that keeps me from sending info via my contact form?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I get this error in the heroku logs:

SocketError (getaddrinfo: Name or service not known): 2015-10-02T19:05:10.892636+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/controllers/contacts_controller.rb:14:in `create'

Here is the code:

```
   class ContactsController < ApplicationController
def new
    @contact = Contact.new
end

def create
    @contact = Contact.new(contact_params)

    if @contact.save
        name = params[:contact][:name]
        email = params[:contact][:email]
        body = params[:contact][:comments]

        ContactMailer.contact_email(name, email, body).deliver

        flash[:success] = 'Message sent.'
        redirect_to new_contact_path
    else
        flash[:danger] = 'Error occured, message has not been sent.'
        redirect_to new_contact_path
    end
end

private
def contact_params
   params.require(:contact).permit(:name, :email, :comments) 
end
```

end

Comment: can you post the code from your ContactMailer class?

Comment: Please post `ContactMailer` class and  `ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings`

Comment: Where are you running this? Local development machine or a server? Perhaps your iptables are blocking the request?

Comment: ruby_newbie I placed it in here for you to see http://jsbin.com/koqudofiye/edit?html,output

Comment: Phil, I was running it on Cloud 9 and it was working fine until I uploaded it to Heroku and then I started getting the error.